# sceptics.stackexchange.com should redirect to the site

Tags: feature-request

In British English, “skeptic” is spelled “sceptic”. However http://sceptics.stackexchange.com does not redirect to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com. For the sake of our friends across the pond, can this be changed?

Similar to how [mathematics.stackexchange redirects to math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1550/656675).

Comment: But we are called skeptics not sceptics. Strong k.

Comment: @Sklivvz: "sceptics" is pronounced the same way.

Comment: I get that, but it's a proper name, not a noun.

Comment: @Sklivvz this is for users to more easily get to the site, so that’s not a real problem.